# What means multiple commas in a macro in c

Tags: c, arrays, macros, hex, c-preprocessor

What does this macro mean or what is the result?

```
#define MOD_TYPE_12 0x11, 0x20, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x42, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80, 0x00, 0x02
```

Is this evaluated to an array?

I couldn't find anything... Maybe because I don`t know what I have to search for ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas don't have any special meaning in a macro, they'll just be copied whereever the macro is used. For example:

```
int arr = {MOD_TYPE_12};
```

becomes

```
int arr = {0x11, 0x20, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x42, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80, 0x00, 0x02};
```

Or:

```
someFunction(MOD_TYPE_12);
```

becomes

```
someFunction(0x11, 0x20, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x42, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80, 0x00, 0x02);
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.. If I would have scrolled down 2000 more lines of code I would have seen the usage of this macro :D

THX

Comment: @user3000289 Get yourself an editor with a search function.

Answer (score 2):

All the

> MOD_TYPE_12

in your program will be replaced with

> 0x11, 0x20, 0x0C

There is no specialty with commas